# Add a second network card in Linux

Tags: linux, networking

There are a number of places that suggest adding a couple of lines to `/etc/network/interfaces`, and restarting the networking daemon `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`. [[1](https://bowerstudios.com/node/1015)] [[2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/778392/install-second-network-interface-on-virtualized-ubuntu-server)]

However, this is something of a pain for a virtual machine for which I only know the desired configuration of the second nic at runtime, and may not want the changes to persist.  Is there some way to only *temporarily* use a second nic, without having to add and then delete lines from the configuration file?

Comment: yes it's possible to do that with the command line but if you reboot your machine all the configuration will be lost. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConfigurationCommandLine/Automatic

Comment: That is exactly the behavior I was desiring.  I will accept your comment as an answer, if it were to somehow become one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes it's possible
quoting from [ubuntu eth0 configuration](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConfigurationCommandLine/Automatic)

> We will use eth0 in this example, your interface can be named
>   differently, see Finding your network interface.
>
> If you have disabled the either wicd or the network manager you
>   probably don't have a network connection anymore. Connect via a
>   regular UTP cable to your router, and assuming you have DHCP enabled
>   do the following:

```
sudo ip link set dev eth0 down
sudo dhclient eth0
```

> This will bring your eth0 up by using DHCP. Your network is now
>   configured (for the time being).
>
> If you don't have DHCP enabled configure your network by issueing the
>   commands below, the gateway address is the IP address of your router.
>   And your IP should be in the same range as the router is.

```
sudo ip addr add 192.168.1.14/24 dev eth0
sudo ip link set dev eth0 up
sudo ip route add default via 192.168.1.1
```

> These commands configure your interface but these changes will not
>   survive a reboot, since the information is not stored anyhwere.